# Datatables Javascript - print with different layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I use several datatables on a single html page which is a report. I use pagination and column management which are all managed through javascript on the jquery document ready. All works fine - no problem.

When I print I need to specify different datatable settings - mainly to remove pagination for each grid. If it was css, you would just use the media tag. Is there any way to do something similar with javascript?

Using datatables print functions is not a solution as I need to print the whole report including the html around it.

One option I will probably implement if I dont get any better suggestions is Leo Lam's suggestion here;
[run-javascript-jquery-only-on-screen-media-not-print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112255/run-javascript-jquery-only-on-screen-media-not-print)

Example of my config FWIW - the main change necessary would be to add  paging: false on print and remove it on screen.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var muttable =  $('#mut-table').DataTable(  
    {   searching: false,
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": 5,
                "visible": false,
                "bAutoWidth": false,                
            },
            { 
            type: 'alt-string', targets: 4 
            }
            ],
        order: [[ 4, "asc" ],[ 5, "desc" ]],

    } );

    });
```

Comment: Can you use the `@media print` rule? (And pop up a page for printing)

Comment: I don't think so - unless i am mistaken, isnt that only for css? The layout of datatable is defined in javascript. 

There is no difficulty with the print bit - the standard browser print will be fine, it is just updating the pagination for that view

Comment: When you use the standard browser print, the `@media print` css rules should take effect-- I was thinking you could use them for pagination at that point.